# Is constructor of class that inherits from another class less effective?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, inheritance, constructor

### Question

In my application I create large number of instances of 'small' class that just hold some data.

I know that class creation (that is constructor call) is costly. My question is: Will it be more costly if I make this small class inherit from another class ? Some fields will just move to the superclass, so basically I'll can just use

*Note: This question is specifically about performance **in .NET**.*

---

### Example situation and demonstration of the question

Consider this 2 cases:

**1. case** consists of only one class. It is the original class:

```
public class ShapeWithOffset{
    public double XOffset { get; private set; }
    public double YOffset { get; private set; }
    public IShape Shape{ get; private set; }

    public ShapeWithOffset(double xOffset, double yOffset, IShape shape){
        //check if arguments are correct/throw ArgumentException if not
        XOffset = xOffset;
        YOffset = yOffset;
        Shape = shape;
    }
    //equality members
}
```

**2. case** consists of 2 classes where second inherits from first. Second class `ShapeWithHorizontalAndVerticalOffset` provides the same function as `ShapeWithOffset` in 1. case.

```
public class ShapeWithHorizontalOffset{
    public double XOffset { get; private set; }
    public IShape Shape { get; private set; }

    public ShapeWithHorizontalOffset(double xOffset, IShape shape){
        //check if arguments are correct/throw ArgumentException if not
        XOffset = xOffset;
        Shape = shape;
    }
    //equality members
}

public class ShapeWithHorizontalAndVerticalOffset : ShapeWithHorizontalOffset{
    public double YOffset { get; private set; }

    public ShapeWithHorizontalAndVerticalOffset(double xOffset, double yOffset, 
                                                IShape shape) : base(xOffset, shape){
        //check if yOffset is correct/throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException if not
        Yffset = yOffset;
    }
    //equality members
}
```

My question is: Is command `var foo = new ShapeWithOffset(20, 10, shape);` faster then
`var boo = new ShapeWithHorizontalAndVerticalOffset(20, 10, shape);` ?

If I used composition instead of inheritance it would be... But what about with inheritance?

Comment: You'll save at best one function call per object instance, which is, if you forgive me the expression, *peanuts* in terms of performance compared to the maintainability and expressiveness you gain from inheritance. Whether or not you should *actually* use inheritance in your particular case, however, is quite subjective and open to debate (and that's why this is a comment and not an answer).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Please consider writing an answer that will express your opinion on using/not using inheritance in this particular case. A lot of good-programing-practice answers (and questions) are subjective and open to debate and still they tent to provide best solutions to (not only) my problems. Often after some debate.

Comment: This question comes up a lot on SO and it always mystifies me. That is, the question "here are two ways to write code; which is faster?" You've already written the code both ways; **try it both ways and see which is faster**.  People seem to think that the community has some magical way of knowing which of two things is faster without trying it. There is no such magical way. Try it, measure the results, and then you'll know.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I completely disagree. This question **can be answered generally** without any particular code knowledge. The only knowledge that is needed is about .NET compiler and virtual machine. I don't posses this knowledge so I'm asking. **The code is there just for illustration** the actual classes might be completely different or not yet written. Note that question is split to 2 parts and the code part is called: "Example situation and demonstration of the question". Please consider it general question.

Comment: @drasto, in your case I'd go with direct inheritance from `Shape` instead of containment, and I'd use constructor overrides instead of defining a subclass for each axis you want to support. I tried to detail that in my answer below.

Comment: @drasto: Let me put it this way: *I do not possess the knowledge you desire either, and I guarantee you I know more about the compiler than the considerable majority of people*. When I need the answer to a performance question **I write the code both ways and try it**. Many years of experience have shown me that my guesses about what really makes a performance difference are frequently dead wrong. **There is no magical substitute for empirical investigation.**

Comment: I'm sorry but there was typo in my question - property `Shape` did not have type specified. It is actually interface. It was corrected. Also see my comment to Frédéric Hamidi's answer.

Comment: @drasto: moreover, none of us possess the knowledge that you do, namely *what you consider to be an important performance difference*. Some people consider a difference of a few nanoseconds to be very important; some people consider a difference of ten minutes to be irrelevant. None of us can tell you what performance metrics are important to you and your customers.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: There indeed is what you call "magical substitute for empirical investigation": in this case just knowledge if base object will be allocated separately or both classes allocation will be merged in compile time. This is not complex algorithmic problem that cannot be answered without benchmark. As I said forget about the code consider it general question - what is faster in any program. The fact that don't know ansver does not mean that somebody else doesn't(see Jakub Míšek's answer). Add:"important performance difference" - question is clear: 'is it faster or not?'=any difference

Comment: @drasto: I don't think it is that clear. Consider for example the question of whether the base call is inlined or not. It might be, it might not be, without trying it I don't know. Now consider the performance cost of inlining; it removes one level of indirection, which is a couple of instructions, which is more time. It increases code size at the call site, which might change the layout of the code in memory, which might cause an extra cache miss. And now you've traded a single nanosecond for a potential multi-microsecond miss! How do you know if that's the case without trying it?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: +1 got your point finally. Ok what I really wanted to know is what was answered by Jakub Míšek. If it will be inlined or base class will be allocated separately as if it was read-only field of subclass initialized in constructor (so inheritance would basically work same way as composition with access right to protected members). Now when I know it will always be inlined (I read Jakub Míšek's answer as 'constructors will always be inlined') my intuition is that in case of this small classes performance will be the same as if I wrote all the code to the same class.

Comment: @drasto: I'm not one to promote an argument from authority (Eric has made excellent points) but have you viewed his profile, perchance?  If you want to know **which** approach is faster then why not go directly to the answer and measure it?  If you want to know **why** then that's a different question and analysis. Your question as stated is: "is command x faster than y" with a hidden assumption about the allocation (and its impact).

Comment: @Tuzo: you got the point. Maybe the question is not really well formulated - that is probably because my expectation were: Either super constructor call is inlined in which case it will have same performance or super class is taken as some kind of nested class and constructor of it is called separately in which case I might have serious performance problem. It looks like matter is more complex but if the super constructor is always inlined it is about same performance for both and that is enough for me.

Comment: @Tuzo: Well I checked Eric Lippert's profile only after my last comment. I generally avoid checking profiles on purpose. Sometimes people with less reputation give better answers then top SO users. They might even be better experts or might not be experts at all but because they are not they understand my problem better then experts that did never had similar one or only long time ago.

Comment: The takeaway here is that every so-called "optimization" makes some behaviours better and some worse. For example, you can often trade off memory against time, or common cases against rare cases, and so on. Knowing whether a particular optimization is actually a win in the bigger picture depends on the details of the actual scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This smells like [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

<strike>The key words in your question are "... I think ...".</strike> If you know you have a performance problem then identify the bottleneck and optimize that. If you are anticipating a performance problem, don't! It is exceedingly unlikely that any performance bottleneck will be caused by using inheritance in the way your suggest. But, if you really want to know in advance, test in advance.

Comment: I consider this an answer but still I want to know what if class without inheritance is faster. My application will have performance problem for sure: there is task that will run for tens of minutes and user will have to wait for. Algorithm is exponential in worst case despite all heuristics I created. And any speed up that I can make is interesting for me. But I would also like to know general answer to this: Is it faster or not ?

Comment: I have deleted the only words "... I think ..." in my question - they were not about question but about another case (if composition was used). Context of my question has not changed.

Answer (score 5):

This will be almost the same.
Calling of the base .ctor will be inlined by JITter and the allocation is performed once only. It will cost you only a few bytes as an overhead.

If you are not sure, try a small benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with micro-optimizing code using a profiler is that method call overhead is negligible.  My main wins for performance improvements have almost always been: caching frequently used calculations, optimizing deep inner loops (usually by using direct array indexing rather than enumeration) and avoiding unnecessary boxing.  All of these are dwarfed, of course, by improving the algorithm to reduce the number of iterations (usually by introducing a heuristic than can exclude branches early or by transforming the problem into separate 'aggregate' and 'detail' phases.)

Comment: +1 even if it does not directly answer my question because it is interesting knowledge for developing my application. I understand all you wrote except of "transforming the problem into separate 'aggregate' and 'detail' phases.". Can you explain what you meant or provide some study materials on topic link ?

Comment: @drasto, it heavily depends on your particular problem, but many problems can be solved at a coarse level of detail, which narrows down the particular area where a more fine-detailed analysis must occur.  This is a very typical optimization in machine vision, for instance, where you can match a pattern in a lower resolution image quickly, limiting the range over which you must search for a higher resolution match.  There is additional overhead to create the intermediate low-resolution images, but this is gained back by the reduced iterations required at fine detail.

Comment: @drasto, On a side note, if you're having performance issues or need to consider them for your application, I highly recommend investing in a commercial profiling tool.  There are a number of them available (JetBrains dotTrace and RedGate ANTS Profiler are two that I'm familiar with.)  They will save you a lot of time and effort, since they profile the code you're actually running and give excellent feedback at a very fine level of detail.  (Be sure that you're running Release build code.)  You may be surprised where the bottlenecks actually turn out to be.

Answer (score 1):

First, as I said in my comment, calling base constructors (and virtual methods) does not affect performance enough to justify losing the maintainability and expressiveness it confers to your program. If performance really was a problem in that case, structured languages would not exist.

Now, from a *design* point of view, the question is reduced to whether or not inheritance is actually profitable in your case. Which prompts a question: why can't `ShapeWithOffset`derive from `Shape`? If it was possible, I'd probably cut off the complexity and do something like:

```
public class ShapeWithOffset : Shape
{
    public ShapeWithOffset(double xOffset)
    : this(xOffset, 0.0) {}

    public ShapeWithOffset(double xOffset, double yOffset)
    {
        // TODO - Check if arguments are correct/throw ArgumentException if not.
        XOffset = xOffset;
        YOffset = yOffset;
    }
}
```

In C# 4, you can even write:

```
public ShapeWithOffset(double xOffset, double yOffset = 0.0)
{
    // TODO - Check if arguments are correct/throw ArgumentException if not.
    XOffset = xOffset;
    YOffset = yOffset;
}
```

Comment: `ShapeWithOffset` cannot derive from `Shape` because I simplified the code in my example. In the real code class there is no class `Shape` but interface `IShape` instead. `ShapeWithOffset` is in the fact generic so it is declared as: `public class ShapeWithHorizontalOffset<TB> where TB: IShape`. I'll edit my question to have `IShape` there instead of `Shape` to indicate it is interface.

Comment: @drasto, the principle still stands: I'd suggest you define a `class ShapeWithOffset<T> where T : IShape` and go for constructor overrides instead of subclasses for your axes. Just consider you want to add the Z axis later, which way would be easier and more understandable: a whole subclass, or a constructor override? :)

Comment: Yes of course this came to my mind. Actually that was my first design. I changed it to this because there are classes in my application that position shapes in one-dimensional space (in line). There is just no y axis in for them. I thought it might by confusing if there where some `YOffset` property. And it wold be also useless and vast of space (as I wrote **a lot of** `ShapeWithOffset` will be created) So I created this inheritance. DO you still think they would better be one class ?

Answer (score 0):

talking generally about inheritance (not specifically this your case) as kuchana  said in his book (design patterns) try to avoid inheritance if not necessary, because of its complexity.
and i think runtime binding may cause in small performance issues, but the main overhead of inheritance is its complexity in design, that is much more important than a tiny performance issue .

EDIT

i now realize that question is about constructing :D.
the following paragraph is true in java , maybe it is true in .Net too.
i think, if you explicitly define constructor in your child class, it wont make any difference , because the compiler will look for a constructor in the child class first, if not found it will go up in inheritance hierarchy, till he! find the proper constructor.